# query multiple tables and combine results into one return table for stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, select

I have several different tables, but they all have 2 columns that are the same name. I want to write a stored procedure that searches one column in all of the tables and returns the result. Ideas? I'm fairly nub when it comes to SQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The operation you are looking for is `UNION` or `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT col1, col2 FROM table2
 UNION ALL
 SELECT col1, col2 FROM table3
) all_tables
WHERE all_tables.col1 = 'something'
```

If you use `UNION` rather than `UNION ALL`, the database will eliminate duplicate rows that may be in multiple tables.  If you know there won't be any duplicates, use `UNION ALL` since it is generally much faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select myColumn FROM Table1
UNION Select myColumn FROM Table2
UNION Select myColumn FROM Table3
```

..etc

-- Note all column names have to be the same and have to be in each table for this to work

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't even need a stored procedure...just use a union query.

```
select field1, field2 from table1 where table1.field1=criteria
union
select field1, field2 from table2 where table2.field1=criteria
union
select field1, field2 from table3 where table3.field1=criteria
etc...
```

Comment: But your query can be placed in a stored procedure.  You shouldn't compare a query with a sproc, queries go inside of the sprocs in which you can add layers of security.  So he / she may want to put this into a sproc.